# Flask URL path not working

Tags: python, html, flask, url-routing

I began creating an extremely simple Flask application as I've done before and I'm getting a 404 error that's going completely over my head. My directory structure is as follows:

```
Site/
----static/
--------css/
------------css files
--------img/
------------image files
----templates/
--------contact.html
--------index.html
app.py
```

The problem I'm having is that there is a button within the index.html page that takes you to the contact.html page.

```
<nav class="main-nav">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">About Me</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Resume</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="contact.html">Contact</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
```

This button takes you to the contact page which works exactly as it should when I'm using Live Server in VSCode. The problem is when I try to go to this page in the Flask local server. Here is app.py:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template

app = Flask (__name__)
app.debug = True

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/contact')
def contact():
    return render_template('contact.html')



if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

I've always followed this basic syntax for routing to pages and it's always worked until now and I can't figure out why I get a 404 error. I've tried leaving a trailing space in the app.route and clearing my browsers cache in case its a redirect error and still nothing. When I open the contact page in Live Server and Flask and place them next to each other they have the exact same url just on different localhost ports. What am I missing?

Comment: @chrisz I added that template_folder and it still gives me a 404 error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your route is named `contact`, but your link is to `contact.html`. Those names need to be identical.

Try one of these:

```
@app.route('/contact.html')
```

OR

```
<a href="contact">Contact</a>
```

As was pointed out elsewhere, the recommended usage is `url_for()`:

```
<a href={{url_for('contact')}}>Contact</a>
```

Comment: Thanks guys, it's always something simple that I overlook I just changed the href in index.html to /contact. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to provide a file name in `href` route:

```
<a href="/contact">Contact</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Do **not** use the contact.html only the route name as follows.

```
<a href="{{ url_for('app.contact') }}">Contact</a>
```

meaning...

```
<a href=" {{ url_for('blueprint_name.route_name') }}">Route</a>
```